# Printed pictures/graphics come out as distorted

Tags: printing, printer

I have a Samsung M2020 that is not printing normally. this issue happened suddenly and without any previous indications. The graphic parts of any document comes out as pixelated/burned. like this:

[image]

Text-only files are printed just fine but any graphic based document is printed like this.

I have tried the following but got nowhere:

1. Uninstall/re-install the printer driver and restarting the printer/PC.
2. Try printing files on a different system.
3. Modifying printing settings such as Quality, "Clear Text" settings, "Edge Enhancement" settings and "Toner Save" settings
4. Printing a different file.
5. Taking a screenshot from files that do not print correctly and then printing the screenshot.

What could cause this?

Comment: Have you tried printing a test page (important: from the printer itself)? And from a different device?

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a spooling problem on your PC. You could also try removing the printer software and drivers and reinstalling them to rule this out.

Comment: @MiG Test pages print fine. There is also a single system that can print documents without any problems. but all other systems print images/graphics like the picture mentioned in the question. I have installed/re-installed drivers on multiple systems.

Comment: Which system would that be? That might be an important clue as to what goes wrong.

Comment: @MiG It's a laptop with windows 10 installed. I also checked to see if anything is different on that system (like driver version, print settings) but everything was the same.

Comment: I would suggest doing a memtest on the affected systems, but considering there seem to be quite a few (how many have this problem?) it would be very unusual for all of them to have a hardware issue. I'm not sure what else to suggest really, except for continue comparing the system that doesn't have that problem to the others. Are they all networked the same way?

Comment: @MiG yeah I doubt that all systems have a hardware problem, but i'll do a memtest on them anyway. The systems are connected to the same wifi network. But I connected the printer to them directly (using usb cable) and got the same result just to be sure.

Comment: do you find a solution for this problem!? i have this issue too :(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Its been self solved and does not require more answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay we found the root cause of the issue.
Bad usb port on the printer side was causing this somehow.